# What does 'cs' command do in vim and why is it that I can't map it to do other things?

Tags: vim, mapping

I have the ConqueTerm plugin installed in my vim so that I can run bash commands without leaving my editing environment. It's cool when you can run Python scripts while seeing you code within the same screen.

I wanted to be more convenient to toggle ConqueTerm, so I added these two lines in my `.vimrc`

```
" quick access to ConqueTerm
nnoremap cv :ConqueTermVSplit bash<CR>
nnoremap cs :ConqueTermSplit bash<CR>
```

I have experimented these two commands before so that I can be sure I won't overwrite existing commands. '`cv`' does absolutely nothing since after I typed these two characters in normal mode, they appear in the bottom-right corner of my vim window, still listening for my next stroke. But '`cs`' is a different story, since the letters don't appear where '`cv`' would, and my cursor would move to the status area, where we run commands such as '`:wqa!`', only I can't do anything there. Whatever key I press I go back to the editing area. And after I edited my `.vimrc`, my '`cv`' works like a charm whereas my '`cs`' still does the same thing I don't understand.

So, as the title says, what exactly does '`cs`' do, and why I failed to map it to other command? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can issue `:map cs` to see what it maps to.

`cs` is not mapped by default in Vim, but I have a hunch you have installed the plugin called [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). That reserves normal mode bindings `cs`, `ds` and a couple others. Check the link for behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

use `:verbose map cs` to print out what `cs` is binding to.

Comment: Great idea! turns out @progo is right. It's because of the surround plugin